# Can you appeal against a downvote on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, down-votes, post-ban

If you are the OP, could you not request for a downvote to be reviewed by some moderators so that you are not the one who gets wrongfully blocked from asking questions, but him/her for downvoting unreasonably?

That you could appeal against anything you feel is unjust to you - like in real life - would be great. If you do it right, you won't have to fear getting blocked from asking questions any more. Creating new accounts just to be able to keep asking questions is getting tiresome.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to learn how to ask better questions?

Comment: If you can't/won't improve then you will continue to be banned.

Comment: Rather than blocking someone from asking questions anymore, they should just give the "non-better-questions" a life span of a day or half-a-day so that it is set for deletion in 12 or 24 hours but left open to answers because even non-better-questions are motivated by a drive to learn and learning is good.

Comment: "you are not the one who gets wrongfully blocked" - You assume people are wrongfully blocked from questions instead of rightfully blocked.  I would only agree, that a feature like this would be helpful, if i could appear upvotes for questions and answers that get wrongfully upvoted.

Answer (score 17):

You may not realize it but creating new accounts just to be able to keep asking questions is not just tiresome but is also likely to result in being banned from the site.

It is far easier to learn from the downvotes and to quickly address any issues in questions which begin to accrue them.

I see no need to develop an appeals process for unwarranted downvotes because it would be a heavy workload on moderators (who are volunteers) and I suspect would almost always result in a verdict of the downvotes seeming reasonable.

I am yet to see a good or just OK question here that was heavily downvoted.

Comment: I agree with you PolyGeo but what if some people collectively bully one answer and downvote to delete it? It has happened to me just now. My answer has all the details and the user and their friends have downvoted to delete it. I'm sharing a link to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72081288/998626

I would appreciate any suggestion on how to deal with such a situation

Comment: @AkshayHiremath I cannot see your answer so I cannot give an opinion as to whether I think its deletion seems fair. In any event I think it’s unwise to assume the delete voters are friends of the asker.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t add the answer screenshot here but it follows all the guidelines and it is polite. Person who commented on it was very rude and when I tried to provide context they have used language like “Don’t care “ etc. The other guy says language doesn’t matter its intent. After I have added more details in the answer they just downvoted and deleted it. One look at the answer speaks for itself. It’s sad we are in such an unfair world.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no way to appeal. See it as a democracy, we all judge what a good question is, and how could you say one's opinion is wrong? You can't. That's why there is no way to appeal to votes. In the case of serial voting, there are systems, not users in place to fix the injustice.

That said: there is probably a reason you got downvoted multiple times. You should work on the quality of your questions. If you follow the rules, follow the example of good questions, then you will be set for upvotes.

Comment: *[Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)* might also help.